# 3 div side by side and mobile compatibility

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs via by this piece of code.

But i want to make them compatible for mobile devices. How can i achive that.

Divs are now flating to left and i cannot see them on mobile. I want to make them visible and when i on mobile then make them 1 icon by 1 row.

```
<div style="width: 810px;">
 <div style="float: left; width: 270px;"><img src="images/icnrac.png" width=260/></div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 270px;"><img src="images/icnper.png" width=260/></div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 270px;"><img src="images/icnprf.png" width=260/></div>
 <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

Comment: A demo with jsFiddle or Codepen would be perfect

Comment: use classes instead of inline styles and then you can use media queries to make a more responsive design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 270px;"><img src="images/icnrac.png" width=260/></div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 270px;"><img src="images/icnper.png" width=260/></div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 270px;"><img src="images/icnprf.png" width=260/></div>
 <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width` of container div.

Remove `width` from here.

```
<div style="width: 810px;">
```

Comment: Yes it has done. The solution is very easy and sometimes it very hard to see easest things.